# Convert Number into words in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I want to convert number into words in crystal report formula:

> 2345

becomes

> TWO THREE FOUR FIVE

Comment: Great.  What have you tried already?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula is ugly but it works

```
numbervar a;
numbervar b := {your number field};
stringvar c;
for a := 1 to len(totext(b,"#"))
do
(c := c & " " & ToWords(truncate(tonumber(mid(totext(b,"#"),a,1)),0),0));
UCase(trim(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add function either in asp.net or in SQL Server.

for SQL Server function code is given on below link.

```
http://ssrsmegabits.blogspot.in/2015/02/sql-converting-numbers-to-words-in-sql.html
```